# Does wind affect brilliant energy or phasing arrows?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, magic-items, weapons

I have an archer character and wind has often caused me difficulties.

There are two weapon properties that work with wind. [Tailwind](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/magic-weapons/magic-weapon-special-abilities/tailwind/) and [cyclonic](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/magic-weapons/magic-weapon-special-abilities/cyclonic/) (with cyclonic being my preferred choice and also lower bonus cost).

[Brilliant energy](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/magic-weapons/magic-weapon-special-abilities/brilliant-energy/) allows the weapon, in this case an arrow, to ignore nonliving matter. Which to my thinking should include wind.

[Phase arrows](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/magic-weapons/specific-magic-weapons/phase-arrow/) are a specific magic item which causes the arrow to be ethereal until it reaches the targets space. As far as I know ghosts are not subject to wind so neither should these arrows.

So are brilliant energy arrows or phase arrows immune to wind conditions?

Comment: Does your GM apply real world Physics to spells and magical equipment?

Comment: Wind is in the rules http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/environment/weather/#Table-Wind-Effects

Comment: That isn't why I was asking. I asked because it is somewhat of a grey area for people and I may have an answer for one of the abilities.

Comment: In the game the DM does use wind effects, but I was hoping to save money if those other effects could also protect my attacks in the wind.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What's happening here is you're asking us to issue a house rule for you.  Unfortunately we can't do that: we're not your DM.

Rules As Written, the brilliant energy and phase arrows don't say they ignore wind, so they don't ignore wind.

Common sense would dictate that these arrows *should* ignore wind, and a reasonable DM might make a house rule to that effect.  But, again, we're not your DM, and we can't make that house rule for you.  :)

Comment: I try to get questions answered before having to raise them to a DM and thus present what others have done.